# Units of an elasticsearch url/uri

Tags: http, elasticsearch, uri

I am trying to identify the various 'parts' of an ElasticSearch url for variable names. For example, with this url:

```
https://elastic:1234@abcd.us-west-1.aws.found.io:9243/proexc.write/_settings
```

Would the following be an accurate decomposition in the various parts of the url?

```
ES_FULL_URL = f'{ES_PROTOCOL}://{ES_USER}:{ES_PASS}@{ES_ROOT_URI}:{ES_PORT}/{ES_INDEX}/{ES_PATH}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the decomposition of URL provided by you is correct, except the last one as `_setting` isn't the `ES_PATH` and its an endpoint for `settings` API, it can be for cluster or for index both as well, more info on [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html).

Since you have not explained from where you got this URL and what is the objective of doing this, it's difficult to give a specific answer and my answer is generic and based on seeing several ES links and APIs.

You can also parse the index-name and see if its valid and represent the index-name as mentioned in [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-name-type-name-and-field-name-rules/133039) post.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at the URL fields specified by the Elastic Common Schema: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-url.html . I would suggest adopting that proposal because it has been thoroughly validated by a large community of domain experts and engineers.

Here is the link to the mapping of the url fields: https://github.com/elastic/ecs/blob/master/schemas/url.yml

Comment: OP didn't mention that he is using ECS and just curious to know the point of providing ECS-url link?

Comment: @glencota -- that makes sense, but that combines a few things into `url.path` . For example, there's no mention of an `index` in any of those.